# Salt: make all files foo/bin/* executable

Tags: salt-stack

How can I make all files in a directory (for example `foo/bin/`) executable?

I guess this is not easy, since when the salt master evaluates the sls files, the files on the minion might not be created yet.

Answer (score 1):

How about give a `umask` with executable for user that put the file into the folder you mentioned.

To work with directory, you can use file.director.recurse to change everything inside. https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.recurse

```
/srv/stuff/substuf:
  file.directory:
    - user: fooapp
    - group: users
    - mode: 755
    - makedirs: True
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
      - mode
```

For additional file create, you need to create an explicitly use(e.g. fooapp) with specific umask, then assign application that write the file with that particular user. 
However, I cannot find ways to setup umask in salt.states.user. You probably need to run some su command yourself.

UPDATE : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

> Note: Many operating systems do not allow a
>   file to be created with execute permissions. In these environments,
>   newly created files will always have execute permission disabled for
>   all users.

I afraid you may need to create a crontab job that do chmod 500 (u+rx) to all files inside the folder. But for particular file, salt still can change the permission for you during copy or managed process.

Comment: Yes, an umask with executable bit set could work, but this would affect a lot of other files. I am afraid that this would cause confusion in other places. It looks strange if regular files (which don't get executed) have the executable bit set.

Comment: You can always create user with specific umask , then give ownership for particular folder i.e. "foo/bin/"  to that user.  Use umask + chown (salt.states.file.managed)

Comment: I still don't get it. I know how to use states.file.managed for one particular file. That's no problem. But I just don't know how to address all files in directory `bin`. On the shell it is easy with globbing: `bin/*`, but with states.file.managed ... I just don't know. Here are the docs for it: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed

Comment: I afraid you need to deal with the OS permission, even umask does not guarantee works.  Salt cannot overwrite default OS behavior.